# SQL Server : update table Convert Int To IP String

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have problem with my example `table1`

```
Name                     IP                         OS        Version
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Jonh        0x20010db80a0b12f00000000000000001      Os         8.184
BoB         0x20010db80a0b12f00000000000000092      WIN        10.844
Alice       0x20010db80a0b12f00000000000000051     Linux       Ubuntu
```

And I need convert or update the `IP` column (`varbinary`) to string. I try to update whole table like this:

```
declare @IP as int  
set @IP =  * from 

select * 
from TABLE1,IP

UPDATE [dbo].[TABLE1]
SET IP = CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), (@IP/16777216) & 255) + '.'
         + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), (@IP/65536) & 255) + '.'
         + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), (@IP/256) & 255) + '.'
         + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), @IP & 255) AS IP
```

But it does not work. This type of declaration work only for one row/IP but this not update whole table.

My original table has over 1000 rows.

Comment: Where do you get the int values from? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: `set @IP =  * from` is not syntacticaly correct

Comment: `000000000gagraeerhaera00548748 / 16777216` is not valid maths. You need to explain what method you are using to convert 000000000gagraeerhaera00548748 to an IP address. Also you have many syntax errors in your code

Comment: `0x20010db80a0b12f00000000000000001` This looks like an IPv6 address, you're gonna need more than four octets.

Comment: @Luka Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your logic for conversion is correct please try the code below

```
  /*  create table table1
([name] varchar(100), [ip] varCHAR(100),[os] varchar(100),[version] varchar(100));
insert into table1 values
('Jonh',        '0x20010db80a0b12f00000000000000001'      ,'Os',         '8.184')
,('BoB',         '0x20010db80a0b12f00000000000000092'      ,'WIN',        '10.844')
,('Alice',    '0x20010db80a0b12f00000000000000051'     ,'Linux',       'Ubuntu');*/

select 
   Name,
   IP= 
    convert(varchar(3), (cast(IP AS VARBINARY(100))/16777216) & 255) + '.'

    + convert(varchar(3), (cast(IP AS VARBINARY(100))/65536) & 255) + '.'

    + convert(varchar(3), (cast(IP AS VARBINARY(100))/256) & 255) + '.'

    + convert(varchar(3), cast(IP AS VARBINARY(100)) & 255),
  OS,
  Version
from  TABLE1
```

[See demo link](http://rextester.com/LRVFY7357)

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '..........˙˙
Ç˘)' to data type int.

Comment: In case [IP] is `varchar` type then use `cast(IP AS VARBINARY(100))`

Answer (score 0):

Should be just simply like this

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TABLE1]
 SET IP =     
  convert(varchar(3), (IP/16777216) & 255) + '.'
    + convert(varchar(3), (IP/65536) & 255) + '.'
    + convert(varchar(3), (IP/256) & 255) + '.'
    + convert(varchar(3), IP & 255)
```

EDIT :
convert to varbinary then to bigint before division and then convert result to varchar

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, IP)) / 16777216 & 255)
```

Comment: Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Implicit conversion from data type varchar to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: what is the data type of column `IP` ?

Comment: Was decimal. After I changed to varchar come out new error : Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '..........˙˙
Ç˘)' to data type int.

Comment: please update your question with correct sample data with your table schema